# Al compilar me sale el error segmentation fault: 11, alguien sabe por qué?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TAM 128

typedef struct{
    char fase[TAM];
    char equipo1[TAM];
    char equipo2[TAM];
    int gol1;
    int gol2;
} Partido;

typedef struct {
    Partido *partidos;
    int numPartidos;
} Resultados;

Resultados * leer_resultados(char *nombreFichero){
    Resultados * r = NULL;
    FILE * f = NULL;
    int numPartidos, i, j;

    if (nombreFichero == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    f = fopen (nombreFichero, "r");
    if (!f){
        return NULL;
    }

    fscanf(f, "%d", &numPartidos);

    r = (Resultados *)malloc(sizeof(Resultados));
    if (!r){
        return NULL;
    }

    r->partidos = (Partido *) malloc (numPartidos * sizeof(Partido));
    if (!(r->partidos)){
        free(r);
        fclose(f);
        return NULL;
    }

    for ( i=0; i<numPartidos; i++){
        j = fscanf(f, "%s %s %s %d %d", r->partidos[i].fase, r->partidos[i].equipo1, r->partidos[i].equipo2, &r->partidos[i].gol1, &r->partidos[i].gol2);

        if ( j!= 5){
            free(r->partidos);
            free(r);
            fclose(f);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    r->numPartidos = numPartidos;

    fclose(f);

    return r;        
}

void liberar_resultados(Resultados *resultados){
    if (resultados != NULL){
        if (resultados->partidos != NULL){
            free(resultados->partidos);
        }
        free(resultados);
    }
}


int main() {
    char nombre[30];
    char seleccion[30];
    Resultados * r = NULL;
    int i;


    printf("Introduzca el nombre del archivo: ");
    scanf("%s", nombre);

    printf("Introduzca el nombre de la seleccion: ");
    scanf("%s", seleccion);

    if (r != NULL) {}
        printf("Partidos jugados por la seleccion %s: \n", seleccion);
        for (i=0; i<r->numPartidos; i++){
            if(strcmp(r->partidos[i].equipo1, seleccion) == 0 || strcmp(r->partidos[i].equipo2, seleccion)==0){
                printf("\t%s: %s %d - %d %s \n", r->partidos[i].fase, r->partidos[i].equipo1, r->partidos[i].gol1, r->partidos[i].gol2, r->partidos[i].equipo2);

            }

        liberar_resultados(r);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenida a SOe. ¿Estás segura de que el error te sale *al compilar*? Un *segmentation fault* es un error en tiempo de ejecución...

Answer (score 1):

Este es tu main. He eliminado algunas líneas iniciales que no tienen nada que ver con el problema para que sea más fácil de ver:

```
int main() {
    Resultados * r = NULL; // <<--- 1

    if (r != NULL) {} // <<--- 2
        printf("Partidos jugados por la seleccion %s: \n", seleccion);
        for (i=0; i<r->numPartidos; i++){
            if(strcmp(r->partidos[i].equipo1, seleccion) == 0 || strcmp(r->partidos[i].equipo2, seleccion)==0){
                printf("\t%s: %s %d - %d %s \n", r->partidos[i].fase, r->partidos[i].equipo1, r->partidos[i].gol1, r->partidos[i].gol2, r->partidos[i].equipo2);

            }

        liberar_resultados(r);
    } // <<--- 3
    return 0;
}
```

Fíjate en las líneas comentadas:

1. Declaras un puntero y lo inicializas a `NULL`, pero posteriormente no llamas a ninguna función que reserve memoria para ese puntero... luego **siempre** va a apuntar a `NULL`.
2. Compruebas que el puntero no sea `NULL`... peeeeero después del `if` pones dos llaves `{}`, con lo que todo el código que has tabulado después queda fuera del `if` y se ejecutará **siempre**. Es facil imaginar lo que pasará cuando el programa ejecute `strcmp(r->partidos[i].equipo1,seleccion)`...
3. Podrás alegar que esta llave está finalizando el `if`, pero no es así... simplemente porque ya has visto que la llave de cierre está en la misma línea que el `if`. Entonces... ¿a quién afecta esta otra llave? fíjate que en tu código abres dos llaves adicionales:

   - el `for`
   - el `if` que está dentro del `for`

   ... Y, sin embargo, antes de la llave de cierre (3) únicamente aparece otra llave de cierre (tres líneas antes)... esta llave cierra el ámbito del `if`. La llave de cierre (3) es, por tanto, la llave de cierre del `for`.

La solución, al error que planteas en la pregunta es tan sencillo como reajustar las llaves:

```
if (r != NULL) { // <<--- Elimina la llave de cierre
    printf("Partidos jugados por la seleccion %s: \n", seleccion);
    for (i=0; i<r->numPartidos; i++){
        if(strcmp(r->partidos[i].equipo1, seleccion) == 0 || strcmp(r->partidos[i].equipo2, seleccion)==0){
            printf("\t%s: %s %d - %d %s \n", r->partidos[i].fase, r->partidos[i].equipo1, r->partidos[i].gol1, r->partidos[i].gol2, r->partidos[i].equipo2);

        }
    } // <<--- Nueva llave

    liberar_resultados(r);
}
```