# Lectura de arreglos de punteros de caracteres

Tags: c, string

Tengo una duda respecto a la lectura de un arreglo de punteros de caracteres.

Tengo este código pero me marca la siguiente advertencia:

`format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char **`

Al quitar el ampersand, se quita la advertencia, pero al querer ingresar el primer nombre sale un error.

Este es mi código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   int n;
   printf("Ingrese la cantidad de nombres: ");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   char *nombres[n];
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
      printf("Ingresa el nombre %d: ", i + 1);
      scanf("%s", &nombres[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Agredeceria que me puedan orientar :(

Comment: Que error te sale al quita el ampersand?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Al compilar me sale el error segmentation fault: 11, alguien sabe por qué?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/126230/al-compilar-me-sale-el-error-segmentation-fault-11-alguien-sabe-por-qu%c3%a9)

Comment: El error que sale al quitar el ampersond es segmentation fault

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esta línea:

```
char *nombres[n];
```

declara una variable llamada `nombres` que gestiona un array de `n` elementos de tipo `char*`, es decir, cada posición del array es un puntero.

¿A dónde apunta cada puntero? Pues inicialmente a ningún sitio, o bueno, sería más correcto decir que apuntan a direcciones aleatorias de memoria. Posiciones cuyos valores no deberías intentar leer y mucho menos sobreescribir.

¿Por qué?

Básicamente porque la memoria es un recurso compartido por todas las aplicaciones y procesos que se están ejecutando en tu máquina. El Sistema Operativo va asignando parcelas de esa memoria según las diferentes aplicaciones lo van solicitando.

Esto quiere decir que si una aplicación solicita memoria dinámica y, por ejemplo, el sistema le devuelve el valor `0x0F123456`, y la aplicación almacena ahí el valor `5555`, cualquier otra aplicación que acceda justamente a esa dirección de memoria podrá ver dicho valor.

Esto por supuesto es teórico (y simplificando un poco el proceso). Los Sistemas Operativos modernos controlan el acceso a la memoria y, para prevenir la corrupción de la memoria, tienden a matar aquellos procesos que acceden a posiciones de memoria que no les pertenece.

Centrándonos en tu problema, los punteros de tu array no se pueden usar así de primeras para almacenar cadenas de caracteres porque no apuntan a posiciones de memoria que te pertenezcan. Para solucionar este problema tienes que inicializar dichos punteros. Por ejemplo:

```
char *nombres[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    nombres[i] = (char*)malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
}
```

Otra opción, esta vez sin requerir el uso de memoria dinámica, sería crear una matriz en vez de simplemente un array:

```
char nombres[n][50];
```

Y ahora vamos con otro problema: El estándar de C dice que el tamaño de los arrays debe ser conocido en tiempo de compilación. Si atendemos a la declaración de tu array:

```
char *nombres[n];
```

vemos que `n` es una variable, es decir, en tu caso el tamaño del array no se conoce en tiempo de compilación, siendo el valor conocido únicamente en tiempo de ejecución. Esto se conoce como VLA (Variable Length Array) y es una característica **no soportada** por el estándar.

Esto quiere decir que si a ti te compila es porque tu compilador trae una extensión que permite que estos engendros llamados VLA funcionen, pero esta solución tiene varios problemas:

- No estás verificando el valor de `n` ¿Qué pasa si el usuario introduce un valor negativo? ¿Y si introduce 0?
- La solución puede no compilar con otros compiladores o, de compilar, el programa podría comportarse de forma diferente (cada extensión que implemente VLA lo puede hacer a su manera)
- Los arrays se crean en la pila, una región de memoria con un tamaño muy limitado. Si `n` fuese lo suficientemente grande la pila podría desbordarse y, en ese momento, el Sistema Operativo matará tu programa.

Si `n` debe ser una variable entonces no te queda otra que usar memoria dinámica:

```
char **nombres = (char**)malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    nombres[i] = (char*)malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
```

**Edición**

Se me olvidó comentar. Los warnings sirven para avisarte de situaciones peligrosas. En este caso tenemos lo siguiente:

```
typeof(nombres) == char**
typeof(nombres[0]) == char*
typeof(&nombres[0]) == char**
```

Como ves, al hacer `scanf("%s", &nombres[i])` estás cometiendo un error de bulto:

- `scanf` espera un puntero de tipo `char` y tu le estás pasando un puntero doble
- El puntero doble apunta a una dirección que no es donde se encuentra la memoria donde quieres almacenar la cadena de caracteres. El resultado será la corrupción de la memoria de tu aplicación.

La forma correcta es aquella en la que no te aparecen los warnings:

```
scanf("%s", nombres[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ese Warning es común cuando se utiliza `scanf` y no se le envía los elementos esperados, en tu caso el resultado devuelto por tu código es correcto.

Si quieres evitar el `warning` puedes inicializar tu array de strings de esta otra forma `char nombres[n][50]`, donde `n` es el **número de strings** y 50 es la **longitud máxima de cada nombre**. Tú código quedaría así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   int n;
   printf("Ingrese la cantidad de nombres: ");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   char nombres[n][50];
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
      printf("Ingresa el nombre %d: ", i + 1);
      scanf("%s", nombres[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```